# Bootstrap 5.x Modal Events Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

As you know with Bootstrap 5, modal operations with jquery have been removed.

When you want to switch between modals on a page that has more than one. You can see that it does not work in sync.

For example, the code below does not work well.

```js
const modal_1_ins = document.querySelector('#modal_1');
const modal_1 = new bootstrap.Modal(modal_1_ins, {
    
});

const modal_2_ins = document.querySelector('#modal_2');
const modal_2 = new bootstrap.Modal(modal_2_ins, {
    
});

const modal_3_ins = document.querySelector('#modal_3');
const modal_3 = new bootstrap.Modal(modal_3_ins, {
    
});

const modal_4_ins = document.querySelector('#modal_4');
const modal_4 = new bootstrap.Modal(modal_4_ins, {
    
});

function close_after_open()
{
    modal_1.hide();
    modal_2.show();
}
```

I don't want to use a promise for transitions in case there is more than one modal.

While operations were carried out instantly in Bootstrap 5 and below, interesting problems started to appear in this version.

As the version went up, the problems were resolved and while it should have run faster, it got slower and worse.